# "Out of Range" error using record function to sort on Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a bit of experience programming but I have absolutely none with VBA. I have been using the record macro function in Excel with success, but I run into problems when I try to do a sort. All I do is hit "Record Macro", then perform a sort by one column. But when I try to run this macro on a different Excel sheet with similar data (different number of rows though), I get an out of range error. The error points to the first line, ActiveWorkbook...

I know this is a simple question but I am clueless as to how to fix this. Help would be appreciated, and please keep in mind that I have no VBA experience.

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ReportExport-3").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ReportExport-3").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "G2:G15"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ReportExport-3").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:BB15")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a filter applied before you run the macro?

Answer (score 0):

When you run this macro on a different Excel sheet, then the code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ReportExport-3") ...
```

is still referring by name to the sheet with the specified name, i.e. `"ReportExport-3"`. What I suspect you want is to refer to the `ActiveSheet`, whatever that might be when you run your macro, so try replacing all references to:

```
Worksheets("ReportExport-3")
```

with:

```
ActiveSheet
```

It should then use whatever the active sheet is at the time when you run your macro.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing all occurrences of:

```
ActiveWorkbook
```

with:

```
ThisWorkbook
```

in your macro.

This ensures the macro runs on the workbook that contains it and not on the active workbook which might be a different one that does not contain the worksheet your referring to ("ReportExport-3").